# SE Chat custom notification sound

Tags: script, chat

### Screenshot / Code Snippet

[image: Screenshot]

### About

[Someone](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/1581/6969) found the current `*beep*` sound annoying and asked for a way to change the sound. Such a feature did not exist, so I created this UserScript which adds a button next to the notification settings button. This button opens a popup which allows you to change the sound that will be played on activity. Four presets are available (including the current one). Currently, only MP3 files are supported.

#### License

Following the figure in [this licensing question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/82035/which-open-source-license-is-right-for-my-project/82059#82059), I decided to release it under the MIT/X11 license.

#### Download

The current version is 1.0.0.0.

- http://www.lekensteyn.nl/files/se_chat_sound_notificati.user.js

#### Platform

In addition to the requirements for the audio notification, a modern browser with UserScript support is required. The UserScript was tested in:

- Firefox 5
- Chromium 12
- Opera 11.50

### Contact

Bugs and suggestions can be reported by commenting, or emailing me at `lekensteyn@gmail.com`.

### Code

The script is written in JavaScript using jQuery. Stack Exchange Chat works with MP3 files, supported by the Flash Player. Although jPlayer supports HTML5 `<audio>`, this is disabled by Stack Exchange.

Comment: @Lekensteyn fantastic! it works perfectly, you rock :)

Comment: You need to restart your browser after installing

Comment: This appears to no longer work. The presets are broken since `or.sstatic.net` is no longer in use, and entering a url to an MP3 doesn't do anything. Everything just gives the default sound.

Comment: I did some bug fixing to this and posted it on Github: https://github.com/murukeshm/SEChatSound. If you want, I'll transfer the repo to you. @SevenSidedDie test it out if you're still interested. I only tested on the latest Chrome.

Answer (score 5):

I did some bug fixing to this and posted it on Github: https://github.com/muru/SEChatSound, and added more sounds. Modifications were only tested on recent versions of Google Chrome, and I don't know the media plugin that SE uses well enough to know if I broke anything.